# Migrating JBoss 5.1.0 to JDK 7 - gives SOAP jaxb error

Tags: jboss, java, soap

we are working on a big project and we're in process of migrating the JBoss installation to use JDK7, currently it's using JDK6 and all works fine, but we need to use JDK7, but we cannot use JBOSS 6 as alternative.

When starting JBOSS if jaxb debugging is enabled we receive the following errors:

```
 [java] 11:57:28,477 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE: Trying to locate org/jboss/security/xacml/jaxb/jaxb.properties
 [java] 11:57:28,480 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE:   not found
 [java] 11:57:28,480 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.context.factory
 [java] 11:57:28,481 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE:   not found
 [java] 11:57:28,481 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
 [java] 11:57:28,481 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE:   not found
 [java] 11:57:28,482 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE: Unable to find from OSGi: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
 [java] 11:57:28,482 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE: Checking META-INF/services
 [java] 11:57:28,482 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE: Reading jar:file:/D:/Product/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/endorsed/jaxb-impl.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
 [java] 11:57:28,483 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE: Trying to load com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
 [java] 11:57:28,483 ERROR [STDERR] ????. 15, 2012 11:57:28 AM javax.xml.bind
 [java] FINE: loaded com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory from jar:file:/D:/Product/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/endorsed/jaxb-impl.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/ContextFactory.class
```

The error is produced when a SOAP request is being processed in the unmarshalling part.

The next set of errors in addition are being produced on a SOAP request:

```
     [java] javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix xs is not bound to a namespace
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.JAXBDeserializer.handleUnmarshallException(JAXBDeserializer.java:110)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.JAXBDeserializer.deserialize(JAXBDeserializer.java:78)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.binding.DeserializerSupport.deserialize(DeserializerSupport.java:58)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.XMLContent.unmarshallObjectContents(XMLContent.java:179)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.XMLContent.transitionTo(XMLContent.java:96)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.DOMContent.transitionTo(DOMContent.java:74)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPContentElement.transitionTo(SOAPContentElement.java:140)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPBodyElementDoc.transitionTo(SOAPBodyElementDoc.java:85)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPContentElement.getObjectValue(SOAPContentElement.java:172)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.EndpointInvocation.transformPayloadValue(EndpointInvocation.java:261)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.EndpointInvocation.getRequestParamValue(EndpointInvocation.java:113)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.EndpointInvocation.getRequestPayload(EndpointInvocation.java:133)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.server.DelegatingInvocation.getArgs(DelegatingInvocation.java:80)
     [java]     at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB3.java:93)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:222)
     [java]     at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:474)
     [java]     at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:295)
     [java]     at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:205)
     [java]     at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:131)
     [java]     at org.jboss.wsf.common.servlet.AbstractEndpointServlet.service(AbstractEndpointServlet.java:85)
     [java]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
     [java]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
     [java]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
     [java]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
     [java]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
     [java]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
     [java]     at org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:460)
     [java]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
     [java]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
     [java]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
     [java]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
     [java]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
     [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

We tried to replace the original JBoss 5.1.0 distributed libraries from the client directory with newest version of jaxws 2.2.7, because some of them for example jaxb was giving some errors(forgot to log them, sorry).

But SOAP still is not working.

If any other info is needed, please comment bellow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately JBoss 5.1 is not supported to run on JDK7, so a part of the visible problems you're experiencing, it may be dangerous to run this configuration in production environments.

Look at [compatible configurations for JBoss EAP 5.1](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/articles/113083) (it should be the same for GA - Community versions). And in the jboss.org forums you've more information about the [incompatibility](https://community.jboss.org/thread/202595).

Why do you really need to upgrade to JDK7? Take in mind that you can have several JDK versions in the same server, and choose with which one you want to run JBoss.